# REST API. Как принимать text/xml в запросе?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, rest

Как можно принимать text/xml в методе

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("SearchClient")]
    [Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml)]
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml)]
    public string Get([FromBody]string request)
    {
        // Мой код 
        //............

        return "Ok";
    }
```

Класс StartUp выглядит следующим образом

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });

            
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
        services.AddSwaggerGen();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.Configure<SoapProxyConfigs>(Configuration);
        services.AddConsul(Configuration);
```

Пример запроса что я должен принимать

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:typ="http://bip.bee.kz/SyncChannel/v10/Types"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
        <soap:Body>
            <typ:SendMessage>
                <request>
                    <requestInfo>
                        <messageId>12144424</messageId>
                        <messageDate>2019-11-11T23:56:38.369+06:00</messageDate>
                    </requestInfo>
                    <requestData>
                        <data xsi:type="ns:DocumentRequest"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns:ns="http://digilocker.gov.kz/">
                            <FullName>Name Surname</FullName>
                            <BirthDate>01.01.2001</BirthDate>
                            <ID>4444646</ID>
                        </data>
                    </requestData>
                </request>
            </typ:SendMessage>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: ваш XML выглядит как SOAP запрос и к REST не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Возможно ли принимать такой запрос в RESt API?

Comment: А что, конкретно, вы хотите передавать принимать? Потому что, "XML у меня не статичный", выглядит как отсутствие понимания, что творится в вашей программе.

Comment: Принимать я должен text xml

Comment: У вас есть данные на сервере, которые как-то использует клиент. Если "нестатичность" этих данных заключается в разной длине списков, некоторых однотипных данных то у вас есть "статичные" данные типа "список". Если эти данные совсем-совсем разные, то есть, в одном запросе будет текущее время, а в другом текст "Войны и мира", то просто разделите их, в своем API, и пусть они выдаются по разным запросам/функциям.

Comment: `Возможно ли принимать такой запрос в RESt API?` Возможно всё, но это: 1) архитектурная ошибка, 2) в этом нет никакого смысла. Почитайте про REST и SOAP - это совершенно разные инструменты взаимодействия клиента и сервера, и смешивая их - сделаете проекту только хуже.

Comment: А как сделать что бы он принимал такой запрос?

Comment: Принять XML как тест, десереализовать его. Еще раз, ваш вопрос для меня выглядит как "Как правильно делить на ноль?". Разберитесь в том что вы делаете и зачем делаете, а потом делайте. Не наоборот.